# Like and dislike system database and query problem?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a website. There are set answers where users can like and dislike the answer according to user choice. But users can only one time like or dislike but not multiple times allowed to the user cannot like or dislike. similar to nowadays social media or youtube like system. I am confused about how to design a database table somehow I know the below table can be created but I don't is the best solution or not or any better solution can be there

```
TABLE likes {
   user_id
   video_id
}

TABLE dislikes {
  user_id
  video_id
}
```

Any better solution can be there for database design for please help.

one more query is I have is that what if user come on that page one's again than how to display the user that you already have like or dislike the post. I don't understand what query to be written to check that. all answers Thank you in advance.

I am using **Mysql** for the **database** and for the **backend**, I am using **PHP**.

Answer (score 1):

Store both in one table:

```
create table likes (
    user_id int,
    video_id int,
    like_or_dislike int,
    check (like_or_dislike in (-1, 1)),
    unique (user_id, video_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

EVENT TABLE()

```
 user_id 
 video_id
 event_type (0 - dislike, 1- like)
```

1. To not allow multiple like or dislike for a video for same user there are 2 ways:-
   a. First check before inserting a event if a event for same type, video_id, user_id exist than don't insert another.
   b. Make a composite index on video_id, enter code hereuser_id, event_type. So MySql won't allow the duplicate event.
2. Query to find if a user already like or dislike a video

> SELECT event_type from EVENT where user_id={user id} and
> video_id={video id}

This query return all the event for a particular user for a particular video after that you can identify by **event_type** whether use like or dislike a video